# outh2 using external form to authenticate with google account

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, single-sign-on, google-authentication, google-workspace

We have a system that is using its own authentication system and I need to make it use our Google Workspace accounts to integrate with Google SSO so that when the user gives their credentials to the webpage, it will be authenticated in both google account and on our web app account.

Google default workflow redirects the user to its own form, so we have the problem of the password not being passed to our server.

Crossed my mind the fact that this would be too insecure to exist, but remember that all users that would log in to our website would have an account created in a workplace totally managed by us.

how could I auth the user this way?

Comment: can you remove the existing authentication for this app?

Comment: No, the company is big, and all our APIs use the same authentication endpoint. Would be very hard(almost impossible) for our team to change anything in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use "Sign-in with Google" -> [OpenID Connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect) to access to the website. That way it will authenticate with Google.

Or add the website as a [custom SAML application](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519) in the Admin console, and use Google as the IDP since the users will be provided by your organization.

Comment: I also found this information about [Integrating Google Sign-In into your web app](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in/)